# Nested query parameters in Swagger 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm documenting a Rails app with Swagger 2.0 and using Swagger-UI as the human-readable documentation/sandbox solution.

I have a resource where clients can store arbitrary metadata to query later.  According to the Rails convention, the query would be submitted like so:

```
/posts?metadata[thing1]=abc&metadata[thing2]=def
```

which Rails translates to params of:

```
{ "metadata" => { "thing1" => "abc", "thing2" => "def" } }
```

which can easily be used to generate the appropriate `WHERE` clause for the database.

Is there any support for something like this in Swagger?  I want to ultimately have Swagger-UI give some way to modify the generated request to add on arbitrary params under the `metadata` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear supported yet (over 2 years after you asked the question), but there's an ongoing discussion & open ticket about adding support for this on the [OpenAPI github repo](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1706). They refer to this type of nesting as `deepObjects`.

There's another open issue where an implementation was attempted [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4064#issuecomment-357417513). Using the most recent stable swagger-ui release, however, I have observed it working as I expect:

```
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "page[number]",
        "in": "query",
        "type": "integer",
        "default": 1,
        "required": false
      },
      {
        "name": "page[size]",
        "in": "query",
        "type": "integer",
        "default": 25,
        "required": false
      }
```

This presents the expected dialog box & works with `Try it out` against a working server.

[image]

I don't believe there is a good way to specify arbitrary or a selection of values (e.g. an enum), so you may have to add parameters for every nesting option.